# Trying to hash a password using salt for the first time

Tags: hmac, pbkdf-2

I'm trying to hash (as secure as resonably possible) a password inside my db.

Per user I have their email, username and password and a uuid4 to identify them.

And for the password I though of using python's hashlib library with the pbkdf2_hmac function.

It takes:

- a hash function I went with sha512
- the password itself (which for testing I went with my max of 1024 random characters (lowercase, uppercase, digits and a couple of symbols)
- a salt which mine is composed of the uuid hashed with the sha256 of the hashlib library
- and the number of iterations, I went with 5 million to test (lib example was 500k).

On my test machine (not that powerful) it takes 5 seconds on average to compute 1 password. Is that good, can I improve this in any way or is this actually bad and I'm overthinking it ?

Edit: mistake from 1M to 5M iterations

Answer (score 1):

I'd bring back the password to normal dimensions. You could try and select SHA-256 which will bring all the security you need and may be hardware accelerated. SHA-512 should be faster on 64 bit processors but it is usually not accelerated.

In this case it obviously pays to make sure you'd use the fastest library available to execute the function. 5 seconds seems very slow for 1M iterations. Remember that using these functions is basically playing a bit of a drag race against an adversary. They'll be using GPU accelerated hardware, but they have to tests lots of passwords to find one that matches. For servers I'd certainly go for a native library if I had to implement this for a multi-user server application. Heck, I'd probably create a separate service for it. [Here's a hint for creating a service using CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66101107/589259) and note the 1s for 100M hashes (!).

Also, please don't ask for more than the hash output size (512 bits for SHA-512 obviously) as PBKDF2 will then do all the iterations once more - which could be considered a bug of the algorithm.

Notes:

- also have a look at the secure versions of Argon2, which can e.g. also use memory
- PKBDF's are only one part of the solution when it comes to password, I'd definitely do things like showing password strength to the user, and adding delays when the password is tried many times (there is a lot more to be said here of course, but that would require me to write a book).
- there are precisely as many hashes over UUID's as there are UUID's, so hashing an OID doesn't make much sense, it is only fed into the PRF once assuming that the requested PBKDF output size doesn't exceed the hash output size.

See [the Wikipedia article on PKBDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to see how PBKDF2 operates.

Comment: sorry I did 5M iterations not 1M I miss read my code, with sha256 it's 4sec average, and with 1M it's 1sec average (with the password set to max 512 chars) and they will run on a machine that's a 64bit cpu. And I don't understand what your saying with the last note ?

Comment: Please also edit your question. Those numbers are somewhat more logical. I've changed my answer w.r.t. to the salt, is that easier to comprehend?

Comment: I found the Argon2 algorithm when going through the links you've sent, and it looks promising, I might give it a go and see if it's better (I doubt it won't be). Thanks for the help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

The inputs of the password hash in the question look fine to me.

Notice that best practice is to have a field (often, at start of the expression of the hash as string) for at least a version, and (in more general setups) the type of hash, parameters, and salt. That lets you change your mind on hashing method, what the salt is, and so on, without breaking compatibility, upgrading users to new hash algorithms when they log in. There are even de-facto standards for such things.

As you have found, PBKDF2 on a standard CPU with a high number of rounds is slow. And you need a high number of rounds, because attackers can use GPUs, FPGAs, and ASICs to run PBKDF2 orders of magnitude faster than a standard CPU can. That's [tried and tested](https://is.muni.cz/th/sah52/thesis-final.pdf#page=49) (or see this [paywalled paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-33167-1_41)).

The Right Thing is to **ditch PBKDF2, and use a [memory-hard function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-hard_function) instead**, like [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) or the older [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt). For the same CPU time spent, it gives vastly better protection against password search assuming leak of password hashes. It might not even be difficult, because [`hashlib.scrypt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.scrypt) is readily available in modern Python, with an interface not too different from that of [`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac).